# Which countries can an individual iOS developer reside in in order to receive payments from Apple?

Tags: app-store-connect

I want to sign up as an individual or as a company and sell apps on the App Store. SInce I have not purchased access to Developer Program I cannot check which countries are eligible..Any other way I can check this?

Comment: Also [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151037/) has a similar answer to mine here.

Answer (score 2):

Apple sells the developer program from the online stores in these countries:

http://store.apple.com/us/browse/open/country_selector

You could **assume that if the developer program is for sale on your country's specific Apple online store, then you are good to go** as far as selling apps from that country to anywhere Apple sells apps. I've not heard of anyone having issues, but maybe there are some bizarre edge cases where you can't sell apps everywhere if you are registered in a specific country.

[image]

Also, each country has local pre-sales support, so you can contact them before ordering if you have reservations about proceeding with payment. They will get you a specific answer if you ask. Lastly, You can even pay for the developer program and then you get to review the terms and conditions. If they are not to your liking, the developer support phone number and contact information is available to you to request a refund which you could figure out within a week or two of reviewing the T&C.

Comment: Just want to add, _anyone_ can receive payments for an app as long as their bank account information gets verified. _Selling_ those apps are restricted to the territories Apple support

Comment: @soulshined I would qualify your "anyone can receive payments" to "anyone that Apple sells a developer program to and then has their legal paperwork accepted" :-)

Comment: touché. What does $99 ___really___ buy anyways.

Comment: Can people from this country (India) create subscription-based apps?

Comment: @VivekSancheti Not sure if that’s what this question thread is asking. Have you searched for a question like this on SO or here? It might make a new question if it’s not asked already.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get hold of a developer license for that country, then as long as your bank account details are valid and Apple support the currency then you should be able to sell your Apps and be paid. However you should contact the local apple online store for your country and ask them if you are concerned about payment systems.

Much of the sales details are available without needing a log in or to receive the actual license agreement. For instance, take a look at the Apple Store Territories list - the list of countries that apple will support.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/AppStoreTerritories.html

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804369/official-list-of-countries-for-iphone-appstore-and-in-app-purchase?lq=1

Below is the (somewhat lengthy) list of countries:

> - Country code Country
> - AE United Arab Emirates
> - AG Antigua and Barbuda
> - AI Anguilla
> - AL Albania
> - AM Armenia
> - AO Angola
> - AR Argentina
> - AT Austria
> - AU Australia
> - AZ Azerbaijan
> - BB Barbados
> - BE Belgium
> - BF Burkina Faso
> - BG Bulgaria
> - BH Bahrain
> - BJ Benin
> - BM Bermuda
> - BN Brunei
> - BO Bolivia
> - BR Brazil
> - BS Bahamas
> - BT Bhutan
> - BW Botswana
> - BY Belarus
> - BZ Belize
> - CA Canada
> - CG Republic Of Congo
> - CH Switzerland
> - CL Chile
> - CN China
> - CO Colombia
> - CR Costa Rica
> - CV Cape Verde
> - CY Cyprus
> - CZ Czech Republic
> - DE Germany
> - DK Denmark
> - DM Dominica
> - DO Dominican Republic
> - DZ Algeria
> - EC Ecuador
> - EE Estonia
> - EG Egypt
> - ES Spain
> - FI Finland
> - FJ Fiji
> - FM Federated States Of Micronesia
> - FR France
> - GB United Kingdom
> - GD Grenada
> - GH Ghana
> - GM Gambia
> - GR Greece
> - GT Guatemala
> - GW Guinea-Bissau
> - GY Guyana
> - HK Hong Kong
> - HN Honduras
> - HR Croatia
> - HU Hungary
> - ID Indonesia
> - IE Ireland
> - IL Israel
> - IN India
> - IS Iceland
> - IT Italy
> - JM Jamaica
> - JO Jordan
> - JP Japan
> - KE Kenya
> - KG Kyrgyzstan
> - KH Cambodia
> - KN St. Kitts and Nevis
> - KR Republic Of Korea
> - KW Kuwait
> - KY Cayman Islands
> - KZ Kazakstan
> - LA Lao People’s Democratic Republic
> - LB Lebanon
> - LC St. Lucia
> - LK Sri Lanka
> - LR Liberia
> - LT Lithuania
> - LU Luxembourg
> - LV Latvia
> - MD Republic Of Moldova
> - MG Madagascar
> - MK Macedonia
> - ML Mali
> - MN Mongolia
> - MO Macau
> - MR Mauritania
> - MS Montserrat
> - MT Malta
> - MU Mauritius
> - MW Malawi
> - MX Mexico
> - MY Malaysia
> - MZ Mozambique
> - NA Namibia
> - NE Niger
> - NG Nigeria
> - NI Nicaragua
> - NL Netherlands
> - NO Norway
> - NP Nepal
> - NZ New Zealand
> - OM Oman
> - PA Panama
> - PE Peru
> - PG Papua New Guinea
> - PH Philippines
> - PK Pakistan
> - PL Poland
> - PT Portugal
> - PW Palau
> - PY Paraguay
> - QA Qatar
> - RO Romania
> - RU Russia
> - SA Saudi Arabia
> - SB Solomon Islands
> - SC Seychelles
> - SE Sweden
> - SG Singapore
> - SI Slovenia
> - SK Slovakia
> - SL Sierra Leone
> - SN Senegal
> - SR Suriname
> - ST Sao Tome and Principe
> - SV El Salvador
> - SZ Swaziland
> - TC Turks and Caicos
> - TD Chad
> - TH Thailand
> - TJ Tajikistan
> - TM Turkmenistan
> - TN Tunisia
> - TR Turkey
> - TT Trinidad and Tobago
> - TW Taiwan
> - TZ Tanzania
> - UA Ukraine
> - UG Uganda
> - US United States
> - UY Uruguay
> - UZ Uzbekistan
> - VC St. Vincent and The Grenadines
> - VE Venezuela
> - VG British Virgin Islands
> - VN Vietnam
> - YE Yemen
> - ZA South Africa
> - ZW Zimbabwe

Comment: Great links - these all seem more appropriate once the OP has a) been sold a developer license and b) had their legal paperwork cleared. The list of countries where you can **buy** yourself a developer license is clearly less than the list of countries where iOS apps are for sale from your list above.

Comment: True. The question isn't very clear. It implies that they can get hold of a developer license but not sure about the payment system from apple.

Comment: I actually love the clarity of the question. It's short, sweet and to-the-point. It's hard to answer well, but that doesn't make it unclear to me. I'm also not the only one to decide :-) If it's unclear you many, it might need an edit. I upvoted it as it stands with the minor tag edit I made.

Comment: It's somewhat unclear to me because the title is referring to Apple paying the person in that country but the text is referring to the developer license.

Answer (score 1):

You can't sign in as an individual or company from at least 5 countries (as of today: Dec 29, 2014):

as consequence of complete embargos:

- North Korea
- Syria
- Cuba
- Sudan

> PROHIBITED DESTINATIONS
>   The U.S. holds complete embargoes against Cuba, North Korea, Sudan, and Syria.
>
> The exportation, reexportation, sale or supply, directly or indirectly, from the United States, or by a U.S. person wherever located, of any Apple goods, software, technology (including technical data), or services to any of these countries is strictly prohibited without prior authorization by the U.S. Government.

- Iran

> OFAC IRANIAN GENERAL LICENSE NO. D-1
>   On Febraury 7, 2014, OFAC issued Iranian General License No. D-1, authorizing the exportation or reexportation, directly or indirectly, from the United States or by U.S. persons, wherever located, to persons in Iran of "certain services, software, and hardware incident to personal communications". General License No. D-1 enumerates certain categories authorized for export to non-prohibited end-users and end-uses in Iran. Some Apple goods and Apple software fall into these categories. For scope and further details, see General License D-1 and the Annex to General License D-1, available from OFAC's Iran Sanctions Resource Center at http://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/Programs/pages/iran.aspx.

[Source 1](https://www.apple.com/legal/more-resources/gtc.html)
Source 2: I checked my apple dev account and the listed countries

Comment: Thank you so much! Also a huge thanks to @bmike and everyone else who answered! Now I have to research what it takes to disburse funds that have been received to the bank account.