# Withdrawing iTunes Connect payment in another territory

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect, in-app-purchase

Can anyone tell me for sure whether Apple pays the developer in Cayman Islands? Do I need to have the developer license from Cayman Islands in order to receive payment in Cayman Island ?

Any resources clarifying my queries are appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe your situation a bit more? Are you a OS developer on the Cayman Islands? Or are you from somewhere else?

Apple does all the administration stuff for developers. You don't need to have a physical location in a country to get the payments from your users.

Comment: @rwzdoom I am working on behalf of a client. He would like to withdraw any payments received from apple for his app from within Cayman Islands. Should he purchase developer license from within Cayman Islands to receive payments ?

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164009/which-countries-can-an-individual-ios-developer-reside-in-in-order-to-receive-pa & http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151037/is-it-possible-to-buy-an-ios-developer-program-for-an-ibc-that-was-formed-in-bel

Answer (score 1):

The Cayman Islands is supported by the App Store to buy apps. This means you can receive payments. The app store is available in [these countries](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/AppStoreTerritories.html).

Please keep in mind: Apple will only payout you monthly if you earned at least 150 dollar a total. If you don't make the 150 dollar this month, it will be combined to next month untill the 150 dollar minimum is reached.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/AppStoreTerritories.html
But this link list Cayman Islands too
I think you are listing countries for shopping Apple Store

Comment: Correct, wrong link. Edited my answer.